# Bottle not getting the background images in the css files in my web server

Tags: python, html, css, web, bottle

i am creating a web server with bottle and python, i can retrieve everything but i can't set the background image

code:

```
*css*
body {

background-image: url("/img/banner.jpg") no-repeat center center fixed;
background-size: cover;
font-family: Quicksand-Bold;
src: url("fonts/Quicksand-Bold") format("opentype");
}

*bottle*
@route('/img/<filename>')
def estilo (filename):
return static_file(filename, root='./views/img')
```

i have to say that the images being called from the htmls are working fine, but this, inside the css isn't. Do i have to write it in another way?

Thank you very much.

the hierarchy is the following: i have de bottle file in the root, then a views folder where all the html are, and then css/js/img folders where the respectives are.

Comment: Could you give a rundown of your file hierarchy in your post?

Comment: Done. I have to say that the images are working in the html when using the normal src="img/image.jpg" so it must be an instruction thing. Like the url("path") doesn't work?

Comment: When you go directly to the URL path, does it pull the image?